# Telegram Bot API answerInlineQuery sends voice files as documents

Tags: c++, audio, nginx, telegram-bot

I'm trying to implement inline mode in Telegram bot answering with list of voice messages. Using `nginx` for serving .ogg files encoded with OPUS and using them in `voice_url` in [InlineQueryResultVoice](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultvoice). After doing some research, I discovered that it worked OK for voice files with size > ~8KB. However smaller files are sent as documents and aren't playable in Telegram client (but they are still correct .ogg audios). Also links are playable in browser.

I use `ffmpeg -i <mp3_file> -acodec libopus -b:a 48k -vbr on -compression_level 10 <ogg_file>` to convert from mp3. Also tried opus-tools.

Example of what I send in a result array:

```
[{
"type":"voice",
"id":"m183802670825221348",
"title":"Something",
"voice_url":"https://<domain>/voice/m183802670825221348.ogg",
"duration":1
}, 
...]
```

What am I doing wrong?